# Javafx How to pass parameters into methods called in fxml Document

Tags: javafx, parameters, fxml, onmouseclick

I'm currently searching for a way to pass in a parameter in a `onMouseClicked` function such as `onMouseClicked="#GetBoxNum"` in my `.fxml` document.

Sorry if this question has been asked already I couldn't find it when i was searching for it.

Comment: I believe the answer is simply that you can't - the definition in the FXML simply hooks the `onMouseClicked` property, which accepts an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`, the arguments of which are generated by the JavaFX platform.  

If you have a specific need or use case please ask directly about it, to avoid an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Using "pass" here makes no sense in this context. You do not trigger the events yourself so you cannot pass anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only parameter that can be passed is the MouseEvent. So the answer to your question is: It is not possible to pass an arbitary argument.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use a  Listener for any specific component you have, and implement it in the controller initializer , and by using lambda expressions(within the listener) you will be able to call whatever function you want with whatever parameters you want.